# Where to Edit the Registration Form Error Messages?

Tags: wordpress, memberpress

I am customizing the registration form to appear in Arabic. I want to edit the error messages and the "Have a coupon" to be in Arabic and I am not able to find the registration form view in WordPress plugin editor.